# unable to access deployed war file in Tomcat

Tags: maven-2, apache-axis, m2eclipse, axis

I am trying to deploy a war file in tomcat using axis2, eclipse and Maven2.i am new to this and created everything by following a article given below

http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2011/01/13/axis2-maven-servlets-tomcat/

I have tried all the steps given in above article and deployed the war file successfully.
When I try to hit "localhost:8080/axis2Example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/" I am getting "hello" message

But when I hit localhost:8080/axis2Example/services/HelloWs/sayHello?name=Max or localhost:8080/axis2Example/
Iam getting 404 page 
Can some one please help me out

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different context paths here:

- `/axis2Example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`
- `/axis2Example`

I guess Eclipse is using the first one per default.

You can set the context path of the application by right clicking on your project in Eclipse and clicking on Properties -> Web Project Settings -> Context root. Here you can set the context path to whatever you want.

Comment: I am using Maven project. So, I am unable to find "Web Project Settings" in properties